# $\log_{10}(x)$ approximation

Tags: logarithms

$\log_{10}x \approx x^{ \frac{1}{2^{19}}}227695 - 227695$

I plotted the graphs of both $\log_{10}x$  and  $x^{ \frac{1}{2^{19}}} 227695 - 227695$

And found that they almost overlapped.

Can you give a explanation of this or can you find how this approximation is approached.

Comment: domain?  It is certainly nowhere close if $x\approx \underbrace{10^{10^{10^{10^{10^{\dots}}}}}}_{10^{10}}$, for example.

Comment: I am talking about the value of $log_{10} x$

Comment: but they are nowhere close.  $\log_{10}x$ is the same form with $10^{10}-1$ underbrace, which is way smaller than $10^{10^{\dots}/2^{19}}$.

Comment: Try plugging in $x = 2^{19}$. You get $\log_{10} x \approx (2^{19})^\frac{1}{19} \cdot 227695 - 227695 = 2 \cdot 227695 - 227695 = 227695$. This is a far cry from the correct value, which is approximately $6$.  This example shows that the approximation is not really a very good one.

Comment: @JohnHughes its $x^{ \frac{1}{2^{19}} }$ not $x^{\frac{1}{19}}$

Comment: @JohnHughes and who upvoted the comment -_-

Comment: OK. Try plugging in $x = 2^{2^{19}}$. You get $\log_{10} x \approx (2^{2^{19}})^\frac{1}{2^{19}} \cdot 227695 - 227695 = 227695.$ The correct answer is $2^{19} \log_{10} 2 \approx 157826$. Still pretty darned wrong. And (no surprise), the error grows as $x$ grows, because...well, because $\log$ isn't a polynomial.

Comment: When you write "I plotted [...] and found that they almost overlapped", which domain did you consider? As pointed out by @JohnHughes, this approximation becomes really bad as $x \to +\infty$ and it also becomes really bad when $x \to 0$ ($x > 0$).

Comment: Sry but , i just plotted the two graphs in desmos graph calculator. And was not able to distinguish the two .

Comment: @John Hughes use calculator and you will get it almost close

Comment: You still haven't said over what range of $x$ you did your graph.

Comment: I don't need to use a calculator -- I can do math myself. :) And doing it shows that the approximation is bad for large $x$, as expected. It's no surprise (See Ross's answer) that you can make it a good approximation for a modest range of $x$-values -- after all, $\log$ does have a Taylor series at $1$.

Comment: @lurker  range was of the  positive real numbers

Comment: That's the mathematical domain of course, but if you graphed it clearly you had a max $x$ for the graph. Your calculator isn't infinitely wide. ;)

Comment: @Mathlover Let's try $x=10^{10^{10}}$.  Then $\log_{10}x=10^{10}$ but $x^{1/2^{19}}=10^{10^{10}/2^{19}}>10^{10^{10}/10^6}=10^{10^4}$, so $227695(x^{1/2^{19}}-1)>10^{10005}$ is way bigger than $10^{10}$.

Answer (score 5):

The approximation is of the form $\log_{10}x \approx a(x^b-1)$ for $b \ll 1$.  This form assures that the value at $x=1$ is $0$, which agrees with the logarithm.  The derivative is $abx^{b-1}$ while the derivative of $\log_{10}x$ is $\frac 1{x\log 10}$  When $b \ll 1$ and $x$ is not too large $x^b$ will be very close to $1$.  We note that 
$$227695 \cdot 2^{-19}-\frac 1{\log 10} \approx 10^{-7}$$ so the derivatives are very close, which will make the curves very close until the $x^{2^{-19}}$ factor starts to matter.  The approximation will be very good for any tiny $b$ when $a$ is chosen to make $ab \approx \frac 1{\log 10}$  The smaller $b$ gets the longer it will stay close.  Once $x$ gets large enough the approximation will be terrible.

Comment: In particular, when $x = 10^{1/b}$, (and when you chose $ab \approx \frac{1}{\log 10 }$ 
 as Ross shows you must to get a good approximation near $x = 1$) you'll get the approximation $\log_{10} x \approx 9a \approx \frac{9}{b \log 10} \approx \frac{3.9}{b}$, where the correct answer is $1/b$, an error of almost $300\%$.

Comment: Yeah , i got it . But then also the approximation is quite good for a large range of number , which can be used in our daily life calculations